# How can i move cursor in on-screen keyboard with external keyboard?

Tags: java, android, input, keyboard, on-screen-keyboard

I am new in Android and i am working to make an on-screen keyboard which can be visitable via arrow(direction) keys of my external keyboard. I mean i wanna move left, right, up and down in the on-screen keyboard's UI (keys) with pressing arrow keys from my external(hardware) keyboard. The key that cursor is on should be focused, when i press an arrow key from my external keyboard the focused key should change and when i press "enter" from my external keyboard it should be operated.(written to the screen etc.) How can i make this? Is there any idea? How can i make virtual keyboard's keys visitable? It doesn't look like moving around a matrix of buttons. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe u need to design your own keyboard for the task & in the background you can implement whatever interfacing you would like to implement between your customized Android keyboard & your PC keyboard.

Here is a sample to get started with Custiomized Keyboard rather than designing from the scratch
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/src/com/example/android/softkeyboard/SoftKeyboard.html

Note:

1.Normally while working with adb you can use your PC keyboard.

2.Certain Issues I faced while working with a customized Android keyboard is that user need to goto Settings to select the customized keyboard.

Comment: Thx for your care. I have already known SoftKeyboard and i plan to use source code of it. The problem is how to add this functionality. How to make its user interface in interaction with my device keyboard's direction keys. How to focus a key in the virtual keyboard. I have really no idea. Which methods can i use?

Comment: Read & try to understand SoftKeyboard code & you will get each of your question's answer.